# How to find strings in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, rows

I need to find all the rows that have strings that begin with:"EC4"
my attempt was:

```
dataset[dataset['Postcode'].str.contains("EC4")]
```

However, sometimes the string contains EC4 also in the other characters..

More in general, having a string: "abcd abcd", ho do I get only those strings that begin with "abc" avoiding to get strings such as: "asd abce"?

thank you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#method-summary) instead of `contains`:

```
dataset[dataset['Postcode'].str.startswith("EC4")]
```

Note that `contains` accepts any regex pattern, so

```
dataset[dataset['Postcode'].str.contains(r"^EC4")]
```

would also work, though it is perhaps over-kill here.

---

`dataset['Postcode'].str.contains(r"^EC4")` returns a Series with boolean values. It can be used as a selection mask, as shown above.

To assign a new values at the selected locations, you could use

```
dataset.loc[dataset['Postcode'].str.startswith("WC1"), 'Postcode'] = 'center'
```

Another option might be to use the `Series.map` method:

```
In [153]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Postcode':['EC4', 'EC12', 'WC1']})

In [154]: codemap = {'WC1': 'Center', 'EC4': 'Center', 'EC12': 'Eastern'}

In [155]: df['Postcode'].map(codemap)
Out[155]: 
0     Center
1    Eastern
2     Center
Name: Postcode, dtype: object
```

thus doing many replacements all in one command.

Comment: Thank you very much, it work perfectly. Just one tip if you can. What if I had to replace this string with another string? for instance sth like: dataset[dataset['Postcode'].str.startswith("WC1").replace("center")]. However, this doesn't work

Comment: To reassign values, use `dataset.loc[dataset['Postcode'].str.startswith("WC1"), 'Postcode'] = 'center'`.